# Reject all functions if one is rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I have a similar problem in dialogflow fulfillment where I need to book any appointments on the Google calendar. I would reject all functions `p1`, `p2` and `p3` if only one of them is rejected. In the code below, although `p2` is rejected, the others `p1` and `p3` are executed (I wish all functions `p1`, `p2` and `p3` were not performed).

```js
function f1() {
    return Promise.all([p1(), p2(), p3()])
     .then(value => {
       alert('ok');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err: ' + err);
      });
}

function p1() {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000, alert("one"));
   });
}

function p2() {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject('reject');
   });
}

function p3() {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000, alert("three"));
   });
}

f1();
```

Comment: Your are purposely launching `p1()`, `p2()` and `p3()` all in parallel.  When one fails, the other functions have already been executed and you can't undo that.  If you wish to sequence them one after another and abort calling the others if a prior one fails, then you need to code `f1()` completely differently.  So, what do you really want to happen here?

Comment: `Promise.all` will reject all promises that are run inside it if any of them fail

Comment: Promise.all is rejected if any of the elements are rejected. For example, if you pass in promises that resolve after a timeout and one promise that rejects immediately, then Promise.all will reject immediately. So, why in my case Promise.all fails to reject all functions? If I use var instead functions, Promise.all works fine. [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all?retiredLocale=it)

Answer (score 0):

Well it contains a lot of code to implement it so I would give short instructions.

1. You need to have a way to reject your request or whatever you are doing. For examples with `axious` we can use `CancelToken` to cancel HTTP request.
2. Now you need to subscribe on each request and cancel the request or whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you need. Functions can not be rejected or not executed if you run them in parallel. You can only notify the internal function code that the cancel operation was requested from the outside. We don't know what async operations are performed inside your async functions. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sammet-3g88w?file=/src/index.js)

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

function makePromise(ms, label) {
  return new CPromise((resolve, reject, { onCancel }) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    onCancel(() => console.log(`onCancel(${label})`));
  });
}

CPromise.all([
  makePromise(2000, "one"),
  makePromise(1500, "two").then(() => {
    throw Error("Oops");
  }),
  makePromise(4000, "three")
]).then(
  (v) => console.log(`Done: ${v}`),
  (e) => console.warn(`Fail: ${e}`)
);
```

> onCancel(one)
> onCancel(three)
> Fail: Error: Oops

Answer (score 0):

The `problem` is you're not returning anything from `p1, p2, p3`. So when you call `Promise.all([p1(), p2(), p3()])` which is actually calling with `Promise.all([undefined, undefined, undefined])(resolves anyway)` which does not have a rejection. That's why you're not seeing the error.

Add `return` in your functions.

```js
function f1() {
    return Promise.all([p1(), p2(), p3()])
     .then(value => {
       alert('ok');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err: ' + err);
    });
}

function p1() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
   });
}

function p2() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject('reject');
   });
}

function p3() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
   });
}

f1();
```

**Remember `Promises` are not cancellable,** if you really want cancel execution part, you can try something like this. I **don't guarantee** this works all the time and I don't think good idea to do in this way.

```js
const timers = []

function f1() {
        return Promise.all([p1(), p2(), p3()])
         .then(value => {
           alert('ok');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('err: ' + err);
          timers.forEach((timerId) => clearTimeout(timerId))
        });
    }

    function p1() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
              alert(1)
              resolve()
            }, 1000);
            timers.push(timerId)
       });
    }

    function p2() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reject('reject');
       });
    }

    function p3() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            alert(2)
            resolve()
          }, 3000);
          timers.push(timerId)
       });
    }

    f1();
```

Comment: Hi @Naren, i tried adding return but it keeps showing the alerts of p1 and p3. I would like that if p2 is rejected then p1 and p3 are not executed.

Comment: Of course, they will call for sure, As you don't know when will execute. I will definitely recommend you to read more about how [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) works.

Comment: Remember Promises are not cancellable, If you really don't want other promise execution(inside promise code), you might need to keep track of `timerIds` and clear timeouts when you get an error.